# does grep -R only work if the command is parameterized by *?

Tags: grep

Very strange situation.  check this out :

```
billy@prog:~/sql$ grep -R temp_exchange *.sp
billy@prog:~/sql$ grep -R temp_exchange *
events/sumup_events_by_exchange.sp:drop table if exists temp_exchange;
events/sumup_events_by_exchange.sp:create temporary table temp_exchange
```

so - the first grep returned nothing back, but the second grep did.  therefore - the first grep should have returned something back as the sought after string was in a file ending with .sp (specified in the first command).

so I'd rather not parametrize this command with * as that seems a bad habit to get into.

Any other way I can do what I want without * ?

TIA!

Don

Comment: grep -R --include=*.sp temp_exchange *

Comment: You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -R --include=*.sp temp_exchange *
```

The last argument (in this case *) tells grep which files and directories to search.
This will cause grep to search a list of files consisting of all top level files that match the pattern, plus (in recursive mode) ALL files inside the directories.

Within these directories you can specify particular file patterns using the --include option.

From http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html

```
 -R
 -r
 --recursive
   Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the -d recurse option. 
 --include=PATTERN
   Recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN. 
 --exclude=PATTERN
   Recurse in directories skip file matching PATTERN.
```

Comment: my sysadmin told me to never enter commands with * in it.  ever.  any command.  so I am trying to abide by that as I think he is tracking what I do.

Comment: If all your toplevel directories follow a pattern (e.g. src_a src_b) then you could change the * to only check those directories "grep -R --include=*.sp temp_exchange src*"

Answer (score 0):

Because with *.sp it is globbing in the current folder. so it is looking to all files and folders in the current folder with .sp at the end.

Do `ls *.sp` to see what you are passing to the command. It is doing the correct thing in your example.

You might want to do `find . | grep "\.sp$" | xargs grep temp_exchange` or a similar variant using find

Comment: `find . -name '*.sp' | xargs grep temp_exchange` would be a simpler solution.

Comment: or `find . -name '*.sp' -exec grep temp_exchange {} \;` :)